# Analog modulation trainer

Tags: analog, communication, modulation, education, digital-modulation

i am making communication trainer as my FYP i am confused on analog communication module .. I have 2 options first one to make different blocks of analog like mixers, filters , amplifiers ,phase shifters and give their input and outputs on the panel so that user can make modulator and demodulator following the block diagram and second option which is to purchase specified ics for every different communication technique like AM having modulator and demodulator which one is better option and  also give your suggestion's to make it better

Comment: Do you have an electronic question that is more clear-cut?

Comment: This sounds like a question that's more about educational approaches than it's about electronic design.

Comment: Sorry i Have changed the tags and first guide me in a direction so that i can proceed to electronic design of my project

Answer (score 1):

Without answering your question directly, I think you should be aware of the problems associated with making a general-purpose trainer. The big problem is handling errors by the student. Lets' say you make a configurable trainer with a patch panel to allow proper connection. For each function you bring out to your patch panel, you must protect against every possible misconnection your students might make. This particularly applies to situations such as tying two amplifier outputs together, or connecting the output of a power amplifier (with a high-level output) to the input of a sensitive device which may not be able to handle such an input.

And it's not enough to put warning stickers on the trainer, either. Some students will take such warnings as suggestions, and do what is forbidden just to see what happens.